# Accessing custom attribute array in d3js tree node

Tags: d3.js, tree, nodes, nested-attributes

I am pretty new to the D3JS library but is it possible to add a custom attribute to the json file for the tree layout to process and retrieve the data while building the tree if the particular attribute is not empty?
For example:
    `{
      "name": "Josphen",
      "id": "1",
      "children": [
        {
         "name": "Ronald",
         "id": "3"
        },
        {
         "name": "Coxy",
         "id": "4",
         "spouse": [
          {
           "name": "baby",
           "id": "5"
          }
         ]
       }
     ]
    }`
Would later allow me to retrieve attribute with id=5 while generating the node of id=4.
Any insight into this is appreciated.

Comment: In principle yes. Not sure what you mean by "processing" though.

Comment: I fixed it. How can I access the custom attr? I tried "select", "attr('class', 'spouse')", ".spouse" all came out either undefined, with array of 15 elements instead of 1, or null

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to retrieve a datum with a particular value for a particular attribute. D3 doesn't provide support for that.